# Referencing SNS Topic that already exists in CDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, aws-cdk

I have an SNS topic that already exists in our AWS environment. Instead of creating a new SNS topic, I want to simply reference the already-existing topic and publish a message to it.

Right now, I have the following:

```js
const topic = new sns.Topic(this, 'AggregateSNS', {

      contentBasedDeduplication: false,
      displayName: 'Customer subscription topic',
      fifo: true,
      topicName: 'MySNSTopic',

      //how to reference existing topics?
    });
```

My understanding is this will create a new SNS topic, but as I said above, I want to reference an existing SNS topic.
How do I do I reference an existing SNS topic in CDK?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You get a [read-only reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/resources.html#resources_importing) to an existing SNS topic with the static [fromTopicArn](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_sns.Topic.html#static-fromwbrtopicwbrarnscope-id-topicarn) method.  A common reason to do this is adding an existing topic as an event source.

```js
const topic = sns.Topic.fromTopicArn(this, 'MyTopic', <topic-arn>);

func.addEventSource(new sources.SnsEventSource(topic));
```

If you need use the [publish](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/api/API_Publish.html) API from your CDK app (to send a notification upon certain deploy lifecycle events, for instance), you would use a custom resource.  The [AwsCustomResource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.custom_resources.AwsCustomResource.html) construct makes it easy to make SDK calls as part of the deploy process.

Comment: You will not have access to any deploy lifecycle events from the CDK code besides synthesizing the template, so I'd refrain from sending any notifications during synth.

Comment: @fedonev Thank you for the great answer!